# How to use ts in Vue.extend? How to dowith the props

Tags: typescript, vue.js

pic1:
[image: pic1]

I have add props descriptions in Vue.extend

[image]

why there is no tips when I typing the key in props?

Or how to deal with the "props" in Vue extends? It seems I have pass a JSON object, but I want to pass an interface or ...?

I have tried pass interface, but it is completely wrong

Comment: Please past the code as code (text) rather than images

Answer (score 0):

You can create interfaces this way

types/index.ts

```js
export interface AuthenticatedUser {
  firstName: string,
  lastName: string,
  twitterHandle?: string,
  location: Location
}

export interface Location {
  city: string,
  state: string
}

export interface Todo {
  title: string;
}
```

```js
import { AuthenticatedUser, Todo } from '@/types' // importing AuthenticatedUser interface

export default Vue.extend({
    data: () => ({
        authenticatedUser: {} as AuthenticatedUser //declaring authenticatedUser as type AuthenticatedUser
    }),
    name: 'Inputx' as string,
    computed: {
      fullName(): string { // Computed Property returns a string
        return `${this.authenticatedUser.firstName} ${this.authenticatedUser.lastName}`
      },
    },
    props: {
      todos: {
        type: Todo[], // declaring todos as array of Type Todo (Todo is the interface)
        required: true,
        default: []
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      this.authenticatedUser = {
        firstName: `Dave`,
        lastName: `Berning`,
        twitterHandle: `@daveberning`,
        location: {
          city: `Cincinnati`,
          state: `OH`
        }
      }   
    },
});
```

You can find out more about this [here](https://medium.com/@toastui/developing-vue-components-with-typescript-18357ae7f297) and [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-using-typescript-with-vue)